# UV mapping/ Image is expanding beyond UV mapping borders

Tags: texturing, uv

Doing some practising on UV mapping, I've imported my image, and selected my mesh where I'd like the image applied to. Seems to work well, but I cant figure out why some part of my image is going beyond the mesh which is selected. ( the numbers indicated in red circle).

Thank you.

[image: uv]

Comment: By default only the selected geometry appears in the UV editor. If you select all your geometry you will see that the other parts also have uvs that seem to be overlapping with the numbers in your image.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so how do I fix this?